# Extract images object of Tensorflow object detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, computer-vision

My problem is that I have ymin,xmin,ymax,xmax and boxes shapes.

I can't extract objects detected, it just display all image not boxes.

What I tried:

```
image_url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/60/Naxos_Taverna.jpg"  #@param
downloaded_image_path = download_and_resize_image(image_url, 1280, 856, True)

import cv2

...

 for i in range(min(boxes.shape[0], max_boxes)):
    if scores[i] >= min_score:
      ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = tuple(boxes[i])
      display_str = "{}: {}%".format(class_names[i].decode("ascii"),
                                     int(100 * scores[i]))
      color = colors[hash(class_names[i]) % len(colors)]
      image_pil = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(image)).convert("RGB")
      print(image_pil)
      image = np.array(image_pil)
      print(type(image))
      import cv2
      rect = cv2.rectangle(image, ((xmin), (ymin)), ((xmax), (ymax)), (0, 0, 255), 1)

      print(ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax)
      cv2_imshow(rect)
```

I use this API: https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/object_detection

Example of one object detection
ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax : 0.6325336 0.2925815 0.92287964 0.40271035
object type : b'Chair'

Comment: Can you please add a **sample image** with **sample coordinates (ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax)** to test your code with? [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax : 0.6325336 0.2925815 0.92287964 0.40271035
object type : b'Chair'  image_url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/60/Naxos_Taverna.jpg"  #@param

Answer (score 1):

1. The Coordinates of the Rectangle has to be integers, not floats!

   <s>ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax : 0.6325336 0.2925815 0.92287964 0.40271035</s>
2. Another issue is the **start point, and endpoint** coordinates should be in this format

   `(xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax)`, adding unnecessary parentheses`((),())` will define integers as tuples, and that will cause errors.

[image: Recy]

```py
xmin = int(0.2925815 * img.shape[1])
xmax = int(0.40271035 * img.shape[1])
ymin = int(0.6325336 * img.shape[0])
ymax = int(0.92287964 * img.shape[0])

rect = cv2.rectangle(img, (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax), (0, 0, 255), 1)
```

Comment: I know, thanks it works! And then I just use image[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax]